# Changing background according as time in android studio

Tags: android, background, calendar

I want to give different image background to my activity. The backgrounds change according as time. The code is as follows:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        ConstraintLayout homeLayout = findViewById(R.id.homelayout);

        if(timeOfDay >= 8 && timeOfDay < 16){

            homeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day);
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 20){

            homeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dusk);

        }else if(timeOfDay >= 20 && timeOfDay < 4){

            homeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.night);
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 4 && timeOfDay < 8){

            homeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
        }
```

But when I run the code, no background appears.

Comment: This code looks correct with respect to `homeLayout`. The next question is, "is `homeLayout` the right thing to be setting the background on?" Please post your layout XML and your Activity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my own answer:

The code should be changed to this:

```
if(timeOfDay >= 8 && timeOfDay < 16){

                    //day 

                }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 20){

                    //afternoon

                }else if(timeOfDay >= 20 && timeOfDay < 24){

                    //night

                }else if(timeOfDay>=0 && timeOfDay<4){
                    //night
                }

                else if(timeOfDay >= 4 && timeOfDay < 8){

                    //dawn

                }
```

the previous if statement for night was (timeOfDay >= 20 && timeOfDay < 4) which is mathematically impossible. So the system got confused.